# c++ pragma optimization vs build flags

Tags: c++, pragma

I don't really understand what pragma does and i have a question.
If i run my program with `-O2` flag and there is `#pragma optimize("O3")` in my code, will it use O3 or O2 optimization ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/chh3fb0k.aspx has everything you need to know.

Comment: Are you asking about Microsoft C++ specifically or C++ in general?

Comment: C++ in general.

Comment: @ClaudiuBbn: Specific `#pragma`s and compiler options are *not* general but always implementation-specific. So it doesn't make sense to ask about those things for C++ "in general", unless you are happy with *"it's implementation-defined"* as the one and only answer.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from an MSVC standpoint, `#pragma` generally behaves independent of compiler flags. From the point where you declare the `#pragma` statement onward, your compiler will use O3 optimization, if you use the `on` parameter, like such `#pragma optimize("O3",on)`

As stated in the MS docs...

> The optimize pragma must appear outside a function and takes effect at the first function defined after the pragma is seen. The on and off arguments turn options specified in the optimization-list on or off.

Gleaned from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k.aspx